# Is a phone's ROM and Firmware the same thing?

Tags: custom-roms, rom, device-firmware

I have heard of Custom ROMs and Custom Firmware, are they the same thing?  If not, whats the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably the same thing although ROM is supposed to be the area / location where stuff is only ever written once (during manufacture / initial flashing).

Comment: Here's a little more detail that I found: **The ROM or Read Only Memory** is the internal flash memory where the core operating system resides. The **Firmware** is a device specific part of the ROM that controls various hardware components.  So the firmware is contained in the ROM but in the context of Android the terms are often used interchangeably.